# Erro 500 no código php com linux

Tags: php, mysql, linux

Tenho a seguinte conexão com o banco:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=teste;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
```

No windows ele funciona perfeitamente quando iniciei o projeto no linux da erro `500`. Já instalei o `mysql` no linux, consegui acessar e o criar o banco.
Existe algum comando especifico para linux?

Comment: Já tentou usar mysqli no lugar de mysql?

Comment: já e da o mesmo erro

Comment: você tem o php e apache instalado no ambiente linux?

Answer (score 1):

Para não dar o erro 500 e apresentar o erro correto /etc/php/***version***/apache2/php.ini e altere a linha display_errors para On.

Em relação ao erro, sem saber exatamente qual erro esta sendo apresentado os possíveis casos são:

1. Usuário, senha, ou tabela incorreta
2. Se você estiver utilizando namespace coloque \PDO ao inves de PDO
3. PDO não esta instalado, instale o pacote php ***version***-pdo